# Importing Jmeter testResults XML data into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, xml, import, jmeter

I have done some tests in jmeter which produces an xml report in the following format

```
 <testResults version="1.2">

 <httpSample t="28786" lt="27285" ts="1304028697536" s="true" lb="/" rc="200" rm="OK" tn="Ultimate Thread Group 1-2" dt="text" by="344754" hn="MacBook-Pro.local"/>
 </testResults>`
```

I created a table in mysql called testResult with columns t, lt, ts, s, lb...and so on.

I was wondering how can i import the content of each attributes into mysql?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either dump your xml data in the db like grantk show you in is link or you have to map yourself the xml value to the db field you need in java, python or perl.

Note that you can output your result in xml or csv

more here : http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html

and here : http://jmeter-tips.blogspot.com/2010/02/tip-8-how-to-save-test-results.html

Answer (score 1):

Most programming languages will provide you ways to  do this.  Python has suds, JAXB Marshalling for java.

There is also this method

[Using XML in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/xml-in-mysql5.1-6.0.html#xml-5.1-importing)